# Por qué no me aparece el Servidor dentro de la lista desplegable para subir mi KB?

Tags: genexus

En una notebook tengo instalado el Genexus 17 Upgrade 1, donde tengo una KB local compuesta por objetos importados de una KB desarrollada en GX19U9.
En el servidor tenemos Genexus 17 upgrade 6.

Ahora bien, cuando quiero hacer a través del menu File el  “Send Knowledge Base to Genexus Server”, no nos aparece dentro del menú desplegable nuestro Servidor.

Tiene algo que ver con la notebook?, ó con su IDE de Genexus GX17U1? Qué me faltaría configurar para que aparezca el servidor y podamos subir la KB ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ulises:
Esa lista que aparece son los que vienen por default o mandaste alguna KB en algun momento (digamos que un "history") que queda local a la instalación de GeneXus.
Lo que deberías hacer es agregar ahi la URL de tu server, no es un "combo" sino que podes editar.
Si tenes el GXserver instalado, por ejemplo, en https://GXserver17.Mycompany.com es poner eso en la URL (y las credenciales obviamente).

Gustavo